# MVC View as a form of questions and answers without getting null on Post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

If I have a ViewModel like this:

```
 public class FormViewModel
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string RenderType { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
        public Result Result{ get; set; }
    }

public class Result
{
        public int ResponseID { get; set; }
        public int ResponseValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to render these questions and for each question there is an answer in a separate list. If user submits incomplete form, the action should return back on the same view and keep the results too.

How do I bind these values considering that the model on the view is FormViewModel and that I have to pass through list of questions and render both text boxes and radio buttons, of which some are required and others are not, and some are dependent of other question responses? There is one question with null render type, it's used just as a label.

I've tried something but I get null when posting to controller

```
public ActionResult Index(FormViewModel model)
    {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            return View("Confirmation");
    }


@model List<FormViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Survey", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
{

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
    {
        var question = Model[i];
        <div class="title">@((i + 1) + ") " + question.Text)</div>

        if (question.RenderType == "RadioButton")
        {
            <div>
                @foreach (var response in question.Responses)
                {
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Result.ResponseID, response.ResponseID, new { @class = "" })

                    @response.Text
                </p>
                }
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Result.ResponseID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Result.ResponseID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: Model is always valid, no matter if I answer any questions or not, and the fields are marked as required

Comment: Just to confirm: You are wanting to bind the values entered in the form after attempting submit an incomplete form?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 sublevels and I have no idea how to tell Model to bind these radiobutton/textboxes, because my counter length is shorter than the actual number of questions. It gets null inside the Controller, but the state is valid somehwow

Comment: Regarding the Result class.  What is the ResponseValue property?

Comment: It's a value user enters into a textbox. For each textbox we hold responseID which we use to refer to the question it's a response for. Now I removed the levels, it's flat List of Questions, I'll have to edit the question. I have a Question viewmodel sent to view as a list of FormViewModel and no subquestions, results are held inside each question for that particular question